# Which gem version works best with rails 2.3.18 and ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

For whatever reason I need to setup a box with ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.18 to host some historical apps.

What's the best version of rubygem for the above combo? The current (`gem -v` => 1.8.19) gives too many warnings, for example:

> NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be
>   removed on or after 2011-11-01.

Comment: How did you install Ruby?

Comment: warnings will definitely display, because support to rails 2.* and ruby 1.8.7 are stopped. If you still want to continue with the older versions, just ignore the warnings.